# ThinkingSphinx & Rails 3 - How to use OR logic on attribute filter?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to perform the following search as [per the docs](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/common_issues.html#or_attributes)

```
with_delivery = "*, IF(delivery = 1 OR region_id IN (001,002,003), 1, 0) AS delivery"
Listing.search 'ipod', 
                select: with_delivery, 
                with: { 'delivery' => 1 }
```

However I get the following error:

```
 ThinkingSphinx::SyntaxError: sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IN, expecting ',' or ')' near 'IN (001...
```

It seems like sphinx cannot handle the IN syntax here, but this does not make sense since it uses this in the configs.

I am not really sure how to move past this, any help or suggestions are appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN()` in Sphinx behaves a little differently to how you're using it - the [first argument should be the attribute](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.1.5.html#expr-func-in):

```
with_delivery = "*, IF(delivery = 1 OR IN(region_id, 1, 2, 3), 1, 0) AS delivery"
Listing.search 'ipod', 
  select: with_delivery, 
  with:   {delivery: 1}
```

Comment: ahhh...I ran into this bug years ago & had forgotten about sphinxes IN function, thanks Pat!